# Using StereoBM to measure absolute distance

Tags: python, opencv, stereoscopy

I am using this code to calculate disparity between two images:

```
l1 = cv2.cvtColor(imgL, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
l2 = cv2.cvtColor(imgR, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

stereo = cv2.StereoBM_create(numDisparities=128, blockSize=15)    
result = stereo.compute(l1, l2)
```

this works fine, but the largest disparity (no matter how large) with the two images always comes out as a white pixel in the grayscale, so the grayscale seems to be a relative scale within the two images.

Is it possible to get the absolute disparity, so I can measure absolute distance from a stereo image?

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is to get the real distance to the scene, you can take a look at the OpenCV sample ([stereo_match.py](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4.1/samples/python/stereo_match.py), [stereo_match.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4.1/samples/cpp/stereo_match.cpp)).

What you need is the `4x4` Q matrix obtained from [`stereoRectify`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga617b1685d4059c6040827800e72ad2b6) that is the disparity-to-depth mapping matrix.

[`reprojectImageTo3D`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga1bc1152bd57d63bc524204f21fde6e02) can then be used to transform the disparity map to 3D map.